# Conceptual doubts

Tags: sentence-construction

As a response for where she is, are all the following grammatically correct?

> "She's out at a party with her friends."

and

> "She's out with her friends at a party."

Do both the above responses mean the same?
Are both of them grammatically correct?
What other way could one respond to mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

Both of them look pretty all right to me. You can add punctuation to the second sentence, which is my suggestion.

> "She's out, with her friends, at a party."

Also a simple alternative to this sentence would be :

> "She's out partying with her friends."

The only problem with this sentence is that, it doesn't specify whose party it is. When you say *"...at a party"*, it usually means that the party is hosted by a third person and the subject is attending it. Here, the party can mean a party organised by an unspecified third person or even a simple get together organised by the subject with her friends. So it is an optional alternative, but it can mean a different thing too.

Comment: Another common usage might be, "She and her friends are (out) at a party."